# TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server - TeamCity 2018

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a repository on my company's svn server.

Now, I want to setup TeamCity with it.

When I enter Repository Url, It gives error.

```
Failed to connect to TFS root: TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server 
https://repository.somedomain.net/svn/[projectName]/trunk/
Technical information (for administrator): The underlying connection was closed:
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

[image]

How can I solve this issue? is it possible to setup TeamCity with this type of repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you select TFS in TeamCity, but the URL points to a Subversion repository. If this is a Subversion repositories, you should select Subversion in TeamCity.

TFS and SVN are different version control systems.

Comment: How can I change SVN from TFS? Can you please help?

Comment: @gopal please, read the documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Configuring+VCS+Roots

Comment: I changed to Subversion from TFS and it is working now. Thanks.